# AsyncTask: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can you help me with this code?
It Returns: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]" and the message points to the line number, where the class "MyAsyncTask" is declared (first line of this piece of code).

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    final GetHeader a = new GetHeader();
    final MainActivity c = new MainActivity(); 
    int count = 0;

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... title) {

        c.Header.setText("Text: " + title);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String... string) {

        c.Header.setText("Mission Complete");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... string) {
        boolean stopCommand = false;
        String title = "";

        do {
            count++;
            try {

                title = "some title";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                wait(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        while (stopCommand != true);

        return title;
    }
}
```

The logcat returns:

```
> 1709-1735/myapps.myApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>     Process: myapps.myApp, PID: 1709
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
>             at myapps.myApp.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:98)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

this is how this activity is launched:

```
public void onClick(View view) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        AsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myTask.execute();
```

Comment: You got a question? And you got an `Exception`? Great, post the logcat ^^

Comment: The LogCat references a line of code where the trouble started. Which line is it?

Comment: Show use the code that calls `MyAsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Change title to title[0] in `onProgressUpdate`

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... title) {

    c.Header.setText("Text: " + title[0]);
}
```

`onProgressUpdate` accepts values indicating progress.

Comment: This is also true, but I'm not sure if it's related to the error message the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPostExecute(String... string) {
                                   ^^^
```

should be:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
```

To prevent such errors always use `@Override`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this as this is manually creating activities is a really bad idea.

```
final MainActivity c = new MainActivity();
```

And fix your onProgressUpdate method

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... title) {
    c.Header.setText("Text: " + title[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all java.lang.Object[] items you have cast to string one by one and then put in to your  java.lang.String[] one by one. Directly it will not work.